# Synonym: table-partitioning -> partitioning

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, tag-synonyms

[table-partitioning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table-partitioning) - 38 questions
[partitioning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partitioning) - 247 questions.

Most questions tagged [table-partitioning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table-partitioning) are also tagged [partitioning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partitioning).

The current wiki excerpt for [partitioning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partitioning) is:

> "Splitting a **database table** into multiple segments for performance or manageability."

Proposing we create a synonym for [table-partitioning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table-partitioning) as [partitioning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partitioning) to avoid the redundancy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tag Synonym [table-partitioning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table-partitioning) -> [partitioning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partitioning) has been completed.